# How to alter table in Hbase using Thrift in Python

Tags: hbase, thrift, python-2.6

I am able to connect to Hbase using Thrift server in Python. I am following this tutorial: [connecting-hbase-with-python-application-using-thrift-server](https://acadgild.com/blog/connecting-hbase-with-python-application-using-thrift-server) to connect to Hbase. **I need to alter the table now**. Can someone please help regarding this? Please note, I am using Python2.6 version.

Thank you

Comment: Is your Thrift server is actually running on the HBase side? It's not ON by default.

Comment: Thrift server is running and I am able to do create table and drop table operations. Now, I wanted to do alter table operations like in Hbase but couldn't find the reference for that.

Comment: Putting a quick example via happybase api in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do HBase Put in Python using happybase API. Make sure the Thrift server is running on your server:

```
import happybase

conn = happybase.Connection(HBASE_SERVER) # uses default port 9095, but provide second arg if non-default port
myTable = conn.table(TABLE_NAME)
myTable.put(b'rowKey', {b'CF:CN': b'TextValue'})
```

The table.put method accepts a rowKey as bytes and a dictionary that maps column family and column name to values. Thee are also other argument options there to play around with, like timestamp, WAL settings, etc. But this minimum example should work.

Comment: Thank you! but, I can't use happybase as this library does not support Python2.6 and I can't move to later Python version. Sorry, I should have mentioned about the happybase. I am now trying to do the same using Hbase REST API.